# Swift: Web View Doesn't Load Some Webpage

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class topLikeWebView : ViewController {

  @IBOutlet var topLikeWebView: UIWebView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.lomort.co.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=252&cate_no=27&display_group=1")
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    self.topLikeWebView.loadRequest(requestObj)
  }

}
```

However, this url doesn't load - `http://www.lomort.co.kr/product/detail.html?product_no=252&cate_no=27&display_group=1`.
Other urls load fine, like `apple.com` or `google.com`.

What's wrong with this? I think the url is problem, not the code.
Then there is any distinction between the right url (can be loaded) or not?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: Did you enable unsecured http requests in your plist file?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this in your info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

If you manage to navigate with this, take a look at the `NSAppTransportSecurity` to add specific domains.

Comment: @jorgesaraiva open your info.plist in a text editor and paste it and it should work.